# Algorithm for taking square root of a matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms, matrix-equations

Suppose $A = A^T$ and suppose the entries of $A$ are in $\mathbb{Z}^+$. I want to find all matrices
$M$ with natural entries so that:
$$M^2 = A$$
How can one do this? I know techniques that will get a square-root of an arbitrary matrix, but I want the full set. I want to be able to do this efficiently for large matrices ~$100 \times 100$.

Of course, the set must be finite because we are working over positive integers and the matrix $A$ gives upper bounds.

Comment: Let's just be clear here: if $A = I_n$, the $n \times n$ identity, then there are $2^n$ possible *diagonal* square roots, each $1$ in a bit-string of length $n$ corresponding to a $-1$ entries on the diagonal, and each $0$ entry corresponding to a $+1$ on the diagonal. So enumeration of "SOME of the roots" in the simplest possible case takes time $2^{100} \approx 10^{31}$. I think you're probably not going to get a quick answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find an invertible matrix $B$ and diagonal matrix $D$ such that $D=B^{-1}AB$. Then take all square roots $D_1,...,D_m$ (all of them diagonal, there are $m\le 2^n$ of these where $n$ is the size of $A$ because every non-negative number has at most 2 square roots) of $D$ and all matrices $BD_iB^{-1}$. Look which ones of these matrices are over natural numbers.

Comment: Oh, I just added that to the question. I'm looking for efficient algorithms for this.

Comment: I have changed the answer. Now you have fewer choices. Don't think it can be improved much.

Answer (score 1):

In a way, if you can generate one, the rest follows, since if you have one solution any other matrix $M'$ will have to adhere to the following set of equations:
$$(M-M')(M+M')=M^2-M'^2 =0 $$
Now, by the definition of $M,\;M'$ they are simultaneously orthogonally diagonalizable, thus you can assume WLOG they are diagonal. even more, you know the eigen values of $M,\;M'$ sutisfy $\mu_i^2=\mu'^2_i = \lambda_i\to \mu_i=\mu'_i$ (These are the eigenvalues respectively of $M,\;M'$ and $\lambda$ is of $A$). Hence to get another matrix that answers your question is equivalent to the condition $$(\mu_i+\mu_i')\cdot(\mu_i-\mu_i')=0$$
For all of the eigenvalues. This gives a complete classification of solutions.

Comment: Checking the integrality of the requested matrix can be done efficiently with tools of field theory.

Comment: This answer can be generalized for not necessarily square matrices using SVD decomposition

Comment: Well...it's a complete classification, but not a complete enumeration; you'd need to write down every orthogonal matrix by which you could conjugate them to get a complete answer. But you'd have to write down only those that conjugate them to integral matrices.

Comment: @JohnHughes Well, I did what I normally do, reducing the question to an integral point on an algebraic variety.